# prelude.ls |> with multiple argument

Tags: prelude.ls

Is it possible to use `|>` with multiple arguments?

```
sum = (a, b)-> 
  a + b

10, 12 |> sum # "Unexpected ','" 
sum(10,12) # this is fine
10 |> sum 12, _ # this works, but is there a better way?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pipe `|>` in more than one argument at a time.

`10 |> sum 12` works fine however.

PS. you could write `sum = (+)`

Comment: Thanks! @gkz, can you show what's the next step after `sum= (+)` ?

Comment: There is no next step, I was just showing you that you could write `sum` as `(+)` instead.